# Android UDP needs to recover from back packets

Tags: java, sockets, udp

So I have a listener thread for UDP in order for it to bring in packets for h264 and KLV.  The problem I have is that it runs great, but if it happens to miss a few packets (I repro by playing a video online), it never recovers and instead is just jumbled frame after frame.  Here is the code handling the input data:

```
private void listenAndWaitAndThrowIntent(InetAddress broadcastIP, Integer port) throws Exception 
{
    if (m_socket == null || m_socket.isClosed()) 
    {
        m_socket = new DatagramSocket(port);
        m_socket.setBroadcast(true);
    }

    m_socket.setSoTimeout(1000);
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(m_recvPacket, ARSTools.m_packetSize);
    //Log.e("UDP", "Waiting for UDP broadcast");
    try
    {
        m_socket.receive(packet);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.i("UDP", "Socket Read Error: " + e);
        return;
    }
    //Log.e("UDP", "UDP packet obtained: " + packet.getLength());

    int count = packet.getLength();

    byte [] newPacket = new byte[count];
    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        newPacket[i] = packet.getData()[i];

    ARSDemuxer.GetInstance().m_inPackets.addLast(newPacket);

}
```

Obviously my ignorance to this is the cause, but I am not sure what the solution is.  Once 3 or 4 packets are lost the count starts being almost every frame and what you see after is just junk.

Comment: Does the problem still occur if you tell it to disregard the lost packets?

Comment: All IOExceptions except SocketTimeoutException are fatal on a socket and should cause you to close it.

Comment: Could it be that you get the first errors because the peer sends too fast and it does not send slower just because you loose packets? I assume that you don't have any explicit flow control to tell the peer to send slower?

Comment: I have added the exceptions and none are hit.  I slowed the transfer down from 4096 Kbps to 1 Kbps and numerous values in between only to see the same problem.  After I have pulled in the packets, I send them to the C++ side of code we already have for demuxing/decoding.  Maybe there is an issue with the code there, but we have that code working fine on 2 other internal apps that use that code.